# Running Visual Studio Extension tests Offline

Tags: vscode-extensions

Upon generating the starter vscode extension project using `yo`, the project's tests appear to run online with no issues, but upon trying to run them offline without an internet connection - the following error is returned:

```
node:events:498
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND update.code.visualstudio.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'update.code.visualstudio.com'
}
```

I am using the following npm script to run the tests: `npm run test`.

Given that none of the code/tests need to explicitly access resources from the internet, there should probably be a way to run them offline. Hence my question, how can I run vscode extension tests offline?

Comment: You might start from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-test/issues

Comment: I have raised a question regarding this on the related github issue, however I am still waiting for a reply: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-test/issues/51#issuecomment-1100676860